# iPhone 5s won't turn on after water damage

Tags: iphone, damage

I just dropped my iPhone in the toilet bowl but took it out after about 3 seconds. It's now totally off and wont turn back on!

Aside from cleaning it and keeping it in rice, is there any other way to fix it? Or is it just gone?

It's out of warranty.

Comment: for the interior to dry out can take few days. Then you can try to find out what is not working.

Comment: Right will do it.

Comment: Lots of silica gel (in those packets labels 'do not eat') is sometimes better than rice as it is far more absorbent. The 'crystal' kitty litter, which contains silica gel also works.

Comment: Make sure you keep constant backups, it will likely eventually fail from corrosion that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question (probably a duplicate?) here: [iPhone 6 water damage dark screen issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224651/iphone-6-water-damage-dark-screen-issue/224657#224657)

There is a [good post](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/how-dry-out-rescue-fix-wet-water-damaged-iphone-or-ipad-3633848/) about using various methods such as silica, Damp-Rid, kitty litter and other products that work much better than rice.

An excerpt from that answer: Try the rice thing for a few days, you have nothing to lose at this point. When I used to take calls for AppleCare I had several customers tell me this worked, the idea being the rice would suck the water out. I don't believe it's really a great idea but it can't hurt at this point.

Having said that, your phone is pretty much toast, per the other answer. When I was lent out to the Apple store, we saw Macbooks and phones come in where the customer said they had "dried it out" but "it wasn't working" a few weeks later.

Invariably we'd open the thing up and see some residual water in there.

Sorry to say, you are probably on the road to a new phone. :( Now if you try a third-party place to repair it, at least the last time I worked for Apple about a year ago, if you put third-party parts in there Apple will never touch it to do a repair. Unlike Macs where you don't "void the warranty," any third party parts in an iOS device precludes Apple from doing any repairs in the future.

**So balance out free (rice) vs. third-party screen (cheaper) vs. shiny new iPhone 6S!!**

NOTE: Apple has an out of warranty replacement program but it's not a sure thing they'll apply it to a wet phone.